# Need help obtaining the thesis of Zygmunt Janiszewski from 1911

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to obtain a PDF of the thesis of Zygmunt Janiszewski, which is titled ["Sur les continus irréductibles entre deux points"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Sur_les_continus_irr%C3%A9ductibles_entre_de.html?id=GZdiGQAACAAJ).

I have learned that this is also contained in a later publication ["Oeuvres choisies"](https://books.google.com/books?id=wYh9tAEACAAJ&dq=oeuvres+choisies+janiszewski&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcqvn42tfbAhVvqlkKHa-0CVcQ6AEILDAA).

Please help me see this very influential paper!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one Polish publication of Zygmunt Janiszewski available [online](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/pmf/pmf26/pmf2612.pdf), from which one learns that the paper in question was also printed in
Journal de l'École Polytechnique in 1912, and this is available [online](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4336477/f11.image) too. And indeed, your paper starts on page 79 there.
In case you can't get this pdf, I can post it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, I think the first paper is not exactly the right one. But it is indeed page 79 in the 2nd document.

Comment: I mentioned the 1st one just to explain how I found the one you asked for. Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, apparently  Janiszewski's name in French was spelled starting from S, not from Z., and so you see initials M.S. there. 

PS. Don't forget to accept the answer :-)